# \item that starts with a number doesn't work with style=nextline

Tags: lists, line-breaking

I've got a list of items and use `style=nextline`. Problem is, when a list-item starts with a number, the `nextline` doesn't work:

```
\begin{example}[style=nextline]
\item[3D]
    Doesn't line-break before this text.
\item[Three D]
    Line-breaks before this text.
\end{example}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of code snippets, it's best to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `example` environment is defined via `enumitem`, but I can't guess how. The manual is clear about `style=nextline`: it won't issue a line break if the label fits in the left margin. So you need to make the label grow wider.

I used `geometry` only to show the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
     \hspace\labelsep\makebox[\columnwidth][l]{\normalfont\bfseries ##1}%
   }\description[style=nextline]}
  {\enddescription}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\item[3D]
    Doesn't line-break before this text.
\item[Three D]
    Line-breaks before this text.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found an ugly solution using \hfill:

```
\begin{example}[style=nextline]
\item[3D]**\hfill\\**
    **Works!**
\item[Three D]
    Line-breaks before this text.
\end{example}
```

But I'd be happy to see a better looking solution to this